# Como eliminar un objeto de un array si tiene la letra a?

Tags: javascript, callback

Necesito hacer una función que reciba dos parámetros uno es un array de objetos (ahí lo tenemos) y dos es un callback, necesito que la función elimine los nombres que empiezan por la letra "a".

El código que hice no funciona, no está eliminando todos los nombres que empiezan por "a", sólo elimina el primer objeto del array.

```js
const usuarios =
    [{
        nombre: 'Diego',
        apellido: 'Garcia',
        telefono: '12343'
    },
    {
        nombre: 'Camilo',
        apellido: 'Garcia',
        telefono: '12343'
    }, {
        nombre: 'ana',
        apellido: 'Rodriguez',
        telefono: '02343'
    }, {
        nombre: 'anastasia',
        apellido: 'Zapata',
        telefono: '42343'
    }, {
        nombre: 'alejandra',
        apellido: 'Perez',
        telefono: '52343'
    }];


const operacion2 = (lista) => {
    let x = [];
    let callback = {};

    callback = lista.find(elemento => elemento.nombre.charAt(0) == 'a');
    let l = lista.indexOf(callback)

    let g = lista[l];
    console.log(g)

    if (callback) {

        x = lista.splice(l, 1)
    } return lista

}

console.log(operacion2(usuarios))
```

Answer (score 2):

Menos es más:

```
const operacion2 = (lista) => {
    return lista.filter(elemento => elemento.nombre.charAt(0).toLowerCase() !== 'a');
}
```

Comment: Aun así faltaría que la primera letra se convierta en Mayúscula o Minúscula, para poder devolver con mayor precisión los datos, ya que actualmente si la "a" es Mayúscula no lo removerá de la lista. Se que el pide que sea minúscula, pero mejor tenerlo preparado por si también se desea que sea mayúscula, por lo demás buenas solución :)

Comment: Buen punto, eran las 2am y olvidé el tema del casing, que bueno que te pude ayudar :D ya lo agregué